# Developing GatsbyJs site on a server

Tags: terminal, gatsby

One of my domain *****.com is hosted on a shared hosting server (Linux) with CPanel. Lately, I have installed NodeJs and GatsbyJs on my server. I have created a gatsby project there (which I already developed on my localhost and is working). Now the issue is- when I run "gatsby develop" command on my server terminal, it creates a development server successfully but I am not able to access it because the access URL is "http://localhost:8000" while I am working on *****.com. I have tried "gatsby develop -H *****.com", "gatsby develop -H " and "gatsby develop -H 0.0.0.0" but can't access. Can anyone suggest a solution for this?[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCrNO.png)

Comment: You need to setup your server in a way that you can access your server's localhost domain from your local environment. This would be a linux question and has nothing to do with Gatsby. Another question ist why you want develop on the server and not your local environment which would be much easier to accomplish.

Comment: @EliteRaceElephant I have a local environment setup and working fine. I was trying to create the same environment on my server, just for experimenting.

Answer (score 0):

To run a `gatsbyjs` dev server on a specific ip / port (without the `gatsby-cli`):

- You pass extra parameters over `stdin --`

`npm run develop -- --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80`

- Under the hood this runs

`gatsby develop --host=0.0.0.0 --port=80`

[image: gatsbyjs listening on every ip 0.0.0.0]